# How can I add style prop as control in Storybook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I am building a design system library in React and TypeScript using Storybook. Most components support setting custom styles using the `style` prop. I am trying to reflect this in Storybook using the [Controls](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/controls) feature.

Consider the following Button story with a variant and an attempt to add a style prop:

```
// Button.stories.js

import { Button } from './button';

export default {
  component: Button,
  title: 'Button',
  argTypes: {
    variant: {
      control: {
        type: 'radio',
        options: ['primary', 'secondary']
      }
    },
    style: {
      control: {
        type: 'text'
      },
      defaultValue: '{marginBottom: 10}'
    }
  }
};
```

What is the correct control type I should use when the type of the style props is `React.CSSProperties`?
What is the correct format for the `defaultValue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in [docs](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/controls#choosing-the-control-type):

> By default, Storybook will choose a control for each arg based on the **initial** value of the arg.

> To use auto-detected controls with React, you must fill in the **component** field in your story metadata:

For example:

```
import { Button } from './Button';

export default {
  title: 'Button',
  component: Button, // Here
};
```

> Storybook uses this to auto-generate the ArgTypes for your component based on either `PropTypes` (using [react-docgen](https://github.com/reactjs/react-docgen)) or `TypeScript` types (using [react-docgen-typescript](https://github.com/styleguidist/react-docgen-typescript)).

Hence, to auto-generate the `style` control, you can write:

```
export default {
  component: Button, // This is must
  title: 'Button',
  argTypes: {
    variant: {
      control: {
        type: 'radio',
        options: ['primary', 'secondary']
      }
    },
    style: {                             // Remove the control type
      defaultValue: { marginBottom: 10 } // Keep it as object
    }
  }
};
```

Here is a snapshot:

[image: control style]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated version of @AjeetShah's answer, if the above doesn't work for you.

`button.stories.jsx`

```
export default {
  component: Button, 
  title: 'Button',
    argTypes{
       style: {
        name: 'style',
        defaultValue: {},
        type: { name: 'style', required: false },
        table: {
          type: {
            summary: 'StyleProp',
            detail: null,
          },
          defaultValue: { summary: '' },
        },
        control: {
          type: 'object',
        },
      }
    }
  }
```

[Screenshot of the above using an `sx` prop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjSh5.jpg)

`package.json`

```
"@storybook/addon-essentials": "6.3.12",
"@storybook/react": "6.3.12"
```

`.storybook/main.js`

```
module.exports = {
  stories: [
    '../path/to/my/stories/*.stories.jsx',
  ],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
argTypes: {
  style: { control: 'object' }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).